# Saving image after performing grabcut opencv sample code

Tags: opencv

i am using grabcut sample code. it is working perfectly. But my question is, how can i save the final image after the required iterations.
 What lines of codes should i add in sample code to save the segmented image ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code and where you think the problem hides.

Comment: https://github.com/shashank2/opencv/blob/e7ef87c3b052cbf02d89d93fd083226926c21c6c/samples/grabcut.cpp  this is the sample code of grabcut in OpenCV 2.1 . To save image i added a line,             imwrite("out.jpg", res);  to the end of the showImage(). but now image is not showing up. Please suggest me what should i do to save image

Comment: @shashank any luck on getting it to show up?

Answer (score 2):

Saying the "grabcut sample code" is a bit ambiguous, but I'll assume you're referring to the sample at [the OpenCV github repo](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/grabcut.cpp).

The function you're looking for is `imwrite`. The function signature is

```
bool imwrite(const string& filename, InputArray img, const vector<int>& params=vector<int>() );
```

where the `filename` is the output file, `img` is the OpenCV structure you want to save, and the `params` are flags (what they mean is dependant on the image format you're trying to save as). You can read the docs to get a fuller picture [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). You can also get a more complete picture of the image IO functions in OpenCV [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html).

In the context of the github sample, you presumably want to save the very final segmented image, after all of the iterations have ran. However, the segmented image is stored as a private member of the `GCApplication` class, so you'll have to get a bit intrusive to access it. You could go about this in a couple of ways (much more elegant than this), but the quick and dirty method would be to just add the lines

```
//fill in whatever filename you want here
std::string filename = "grab_seg.png";
cv::imwrite(filename, res);
```

to the end of the `showImage()` method (e.g. around line 130). This will write out the segmented image that you see at the end of each iteration. The output image will overwrite itself each time, and in the end you'll be left with the final segmentation.

Just as a disclaimer, this isn't tested. Also this was written under the assumption that you're working off of the github samples, so take it with a grain of salt.

EDIT: in regards to your comments, here's the (lightly) modified `showImage` method. This is the only change needed if you want to have the final segmented image saved to disk

```
void GCApplication::showImage() const
{
    //same as in the github sample...
    //...
    imshow( *winName, res );

    //the only addition to the code. Writes a PNG image out to the current directory
    std::string fname = "grabcut_img.png";
    imwrite(fname, res);
}
```

Comment: Yes i am using the same code as it is given in github                I tried this one but still its not working. can you please provide me some other ways

Comment: @shashank Alright, you'll have to be more specifi however. Maybe edit into the question what you've tried, that way it'll be easier for us to diagnose the problem(s). Also, try offering a bit more information about what's wrong; e.g. is the image not showing up, or is it not being written at all?

Comment: are you sure? I just tried it out and it works for me, although I'm not sure of what system you're using. I'll add the relevant portion of the code...

Comment: I am working with windows 8 and using sample code of grabcut given in OpenCV 2.1. I used what u have suggested but still facing same problem, image is not showing up. I think sample code of OpenCV 2.1 and sample code given at github is little bit different

Comment: Ah alright, although I think that shouldn't affect the results. Try adding in the above code and see how it works for you, and if that fails then post the code you're using.

Comment: https://github.com/shashank2/opencv/blob/e7ef87c3b052cbf02d89d93fd083226926c21c6c/samples/grabcut.cpp    Please see code here

Comment: when i am using sample code provided by you at github, it is showing error like    EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY is undefined, waitkey is undefined and many more

Comment: @shashank didn't you say the application was working before? The `EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY` is orthogonal to the addition of a call to imwrite (it's some flag in OpenCV's highgui module). It could be that you're using OpenCV 2.1, while the github sample is assuming the latest (2.4.5). But those are the official OpenCV samples, so if you're getting errors on those parts then its because of your OpenCV installation or configuration.